# What are the original Sanskrit verses where astronomical and seasonal references are made in Mahabharata, and the internal chronology of the verses?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, kali-yuga, vyasa

This is regarding the research of dating of Mahabharatha War.

There are too many speculations on internet ranging from 6000 BC to 500 BC all giving their own explanations with different interpretations of astronomical verses present in Mahabharatha.

I am looking for a through resource, interpretation agnostic, all the original Sanskrit verses and rough literal translation, which makes references to Astronomy, Seasons, Internal timelines etc in chronological order.

I found many but all of them seem to be incomplete, while they mention some, they miss out on others.
I will put some helpful resource links in comment section

Comment: https://archive.org/details/AstronomicalReferencesInMahabharata

Comment: http://www.vedicastronomy.net/mb_mahabharatha.htm

Comment: https://indictales.com/2017/02/06/astronomical-references-in-mahabharat-and-the-av-observation/

Comment: https://nileshoak.wordpress.com/category/bhishma-nirvana/

Comment: https://nileshoak.wordpress.com/2016/01/31/importance-of-bhishma-nirvana-for-ancient-indian-history/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLceUJnXydg

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8wT_zX57IA

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icrE36Wodq4

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt1mBTIjSso&list=PLUYylbabKN-c6-x5Vvoto2A-jmoKa4ne5

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9-RmVeNCRk

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIG86YqfK-E

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0uQ40YKrtU

Comment: Better add them in question body itself!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYOSEoclmzOwt5XuqKpGdd9zzMQtgoHbj

Comment: simple - current Panchang (traditional calendar) says were are in kali yug year 5121. and Kali yug started when Krishna left. and Krishna avatara on earth was for ~120 years. and Mahabharat happened within that time, somewhere towards the end. so it happened approx. 5120+ years ago.

Comment: @ram its not so simple

Comment: it is that simple.

Comment: @ram please refer to the work of Nilesh Oak, Manish pandit etc. Current panchang is really flawed. Because if you go back 5121 years and see horoscope you will not find the planets where it is mentioned in Mahabharata.

Comment: @ram https://youtu.be/Y2dm24eIYC0

Comment: @ram there are other restrictions uttarayana has to fall on close to magha shukla ashtamai, mars should be in vakra near jyeshta, Balarama piligrimage dates have to match, twin eclipses etc etc. It should all match with that date.